# Android studio debug working on the main activity, but not do anything with other activities

Tags: android, android-studio, android-debugging

I have a problem with **Android studio 3.0.1**, I'm trying to debug my app on virtual device.

The debugger is stopped only on breakpoints in the Main Activity, but ignore all breakpoints in the other activities

**How to solve this?**

Comment: Provide the relevant code. We can not guess your issues without any code.

Comment: i found the problem, i did a mistake when i call the layout, i called it without using the 'Intent' object.